# php PCRE functions very slow

Tags: php, preg-match, pcre

I create a simple script for search words inside a txt file.

```
<?php
$search_term = "lorem";
$file = file('textfile.txt');

foreach($file as $line_number => $line){
   $row = preg_match('/' . $search_term . '/i', $line);
   echo $row;
}
```

The TXT file have > 7000 lines, in total ~ 6 MB

In php 5.6, 7.0 or 7.1 the script runs in 60 - 100 ms., but in php >= 7.2 the time of execution up to 3.5 seconds.

I compare the php.ini files for each versión and I dont see any diference for PCRE options.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its a simple word. I modify question por reflect the variable. Thanks.

Comment: _"its a simple word"_ - then why regular expressions to begin with, why not just check using `stripos`?

Comment: @CBroe thnaks for response. I think it, but in a future the functión can get regular expression. The question is that in php < 7.2 works perfectly, but in php 7.2+ works slowly.

Comment: Show us a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work better for you, and its lightning fast.

```
$words=explode(' ',$words);
$words=implode('|',$words);
$search=shell_exec( "grep -E '{$words}' data.txt");
$search=explode('\n',$search);
foreach($search as $line){echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';};
```

The method you outlined will also use a lot of ram. My example will use next to nothing.